# How to print pass/fail telnet results with ip and port number?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I trying to print IP along with port no which is not connected or connected, currently I am getting results in two files but it does not telling me which is failed or completed on which port.

```
LOG_OK=/var/opt/Logs/port-check-success.log
LOG_FAIL=/var/opt/Logs/port-check-failed.log
for host in 1.1.11.1 2.2.2.1 5.6.61.3
do
for port in 80 443
do
if timeout 5 telnet -c $host $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Escape; then
echo  "$port: Connected" >> $LOG_OK
else
echo "$port : no connection" >> $LOG_FAIL
fi
done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
LOG_OK=/var/opt/Logs/port-check.log
for host in 1.1.11.1 2.2.2.1 5.6.61.3
do
        checkp80=$(nmap -p 80 $host | grep 80 | awk '{print $2}')
        checkp443=$(nmap -p 443 $host | grep 443 | awk '{print $2}' )
echo $host "Port80:"$checkp80 "Port443:"$checkp443 >> $LOG_OK
done
```

or with your original script

```
LOG_OK=/var/opt/Logs/port-check-success.log
LOG_FAIL=/var/opt/Logs/port-check-failed.log
for host in 1.1.11.1 2.2.2.1 5.6.61.3
do
for port in 80 443
do
if timeout 5 telnet -c $host $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Escape; then
echo  "$host: $port: Connected" >> $LOG_OK
else
echo "$host: $port : no connection" >> $LOG_FAIL
fi
done
done
```

Comment: but where log fail will go !!!? Also mine is doing telnet but I am not seeing telnet in your script !

Comment: anyway I just tried on one of my linux test box its showing nmap command not found !!!!

can you please help me with my original script.

Comment: I suggest you install nmap scanner, this script will log data into one file, where you can see open/closed ports 80/443 of each host related, also I edited your script